# Hermite and Bernstein Style Basis

Tags: polynomials

I was going through a paper titled "Hermite and Bernstein Style Basis Functions for Cubic Serendipity Spaces" and came across this in page 9

B = [ I | B']

What does this equation mean? Is it a simple concatenation of two matrices?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

evidently it is just  side by side, instead of augmenting with a single column on the right it is four columns on the right. We know this because he says the result $\mathbb B$ is a 12 by 16 matrix and that  $\mathbb B'$ is a 12 by 4 matrix. Concatenation seems a good word for it

http://arxiv.org/abs/1208.5973